# Is it possible to set TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED for particular user in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, locking

I have many users for MYSQL database some has Read access only and some has Read and Write access.

Read access users are Report Users which usually create queries which results in high volume data and puts lock on tables used hence system users who are using system at that time get lock and wait period are very high

Is it possible to set TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED for particular user in MYSQL

Or is there any way out of this

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot set the ISOLATION LEVEL for a particular user.

As far as what I can think of you can change the Isolation level of MYSQL which is REPEATABLE READ which means locks will be placed for each operation. So you can set the global ISOLATION LEVEL like this:

```
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
```

You can also go through this article: [mysql with nolock](https://web.archive.org/web/20100814144042/http://sqldba.org/articles/22-mysql-with-nolock.aspx)

Comment: Rahul Thanks for Answering but if I set transaction level uncomitted globally how does it effects DML operations or does it has any side effects on database Transactions or Read\Write operations or Performance.